# SSL error - certificate verify failed - AWS IOT (basicPubSub.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use the AWS IoT basicPubSub.py script to test my AWS connection, but I keep getting this error. I have tried various fixes, but cannot resolve the problem.

I have tried it using my MacBook and RPi and still have the same issue.

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)

Comment: Which command are you using? $ python AWS_IoT_basicPubSub.py -k ...... -e ...... ? Do you have the public/private certificates and rootCA.pem also ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how I managed to fix this problem, I tried the following items to fix the problem:

Re-created all the certificates
Re-installated CLI using sudo
Installed ssl (sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev)
I going to do a fresh installation on my RPi and repeat the steps to understand how this was resolved and fixed.